# Access Appending Data from an Updating Excel Sheet

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, append

I've created a query to copy all data from one table to another and only if it doesn't already exist, however I am running into another problem now. The table I'm trying to copy from has a lot of NULL values and I'd like to exclude this data. How would I get around this?

```
INSERT INTO [Table B] ( [Item Number] )
SELECT [Table A].[Item Number]
FROM [Table A]
WHERE [Table A].[Item Number] NOT IN (SELECT [Item Number] FROM [Table B]);
```

Thanks Stack team!

Comment: So, I managed to get it kind of working.... with

`INSERT INTO [Table B] ( [Item Number] )
SELECT [Table A].[Item Number]
FROM [Table A]
WHERE [Table A].[Item Number] NOT IN (SELECT [Item Number] FROM [Table B])
AND [Table A].[Item Number] IS NOT NULL;`

However it's now asking me to "_Enter Parameter Value_"

Comment: Just did a test and the query works for me. Records inserted and the Null records were ignored. No prompt and it did not matter were the NOT keyword was positioned.

Comment: That's so weird... I've literally got it copy pasted and it's asking me for a parameter value. Could it be, because [Table A] is a linked excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I would not have thought so but do a test - import the spreadsheet to a local table and use the table as source. Does it work?

Comment: the excel spreadsheet it's linked to has somewhere around 4000 extra empty cells and Access is still creating rows of these blank cells, so my idea is that I could replicate this table into a new table and remove all the blank cell; as I am not able to edit the Excel spreadsheet...

Comment: Tested it on a blank Access and seemed to work fine, but when it's a linked Excel Spreadsheet it doesn't want to accept it for some reason...

Comment: Got the spreadsheet to work without prompt? Could be the Excel cells aren't really Null. Try: `AND [Table A].[Item Number] & "" <> ""`

Comment: Hey June7,
After some hard work, it's finally working! Not sure what happened, but it's not copying any of the NULL values anymore, I'm still using my original query for it too. I'm thinking that some one on the back end of the Excel spreadsheet did something and didn't tell anyone.
Thanks again for all your help